# Outlook Tag Plugin

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, plugins, tags

Does anyone from here knows a possibility/method or pluging which will allow me to add tags/keywords to emails that I receive in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This saved my life

[Taglocity](http://www.taglocity.com/index.html)

Comment: @doug any time bud

Comment: Unfortunately, the website and product don't exist anymore. Any free alternatives? Taglocity can still be downloaded on various places, but I am not sure if it is a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

It's called Categories in Outlook 2007 and it's built in. I use it all the time - I have a few standard categories that I can right click the email to add, or I can type in new ones. If I also flag the message it appears in my Tasks, sorted by Category. Excellent functionality.

Using the built-in search I can also specify categories to search within by clicking or typing

category:="Some category"

in the search field..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't become happy with standard outlook rules and pre-defined categories. Now I created a VBA macro, which is automatically triggered on every new mail and can easily do to it, whatever I want. For example, adding prefixes to the subject or attach categories (even new ones). I don't move messages to subfolders anymore. Instead I configure virtual folders to display by customer or project.

One completely automatic thing is that this macro looks at all recipients and the sender, and adds all domain names (following the @) as categories. They are displayed nicely on top of the mail. This makes sense, because all of my customers use own domain names. If they were using gmail, it would of course make no sense.

I can add an example later, if anyone asks for it :)